# Deezer API / how to work with "Deezer Familly"

Tags: deezer

I do not see anything about deezer Familly for the API.
How can I work with different Deezer Familly Profile ? 
Like today Bose Soundtouch App : When user logs, he can not select profile so it only works on Main Profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "Family" feature is not yet available on the REST API / SDKs.

Comment: Normally it should, but I can't tell you when exactly, sorry.

Comment: Hello, any news about this?